# No symbols found Atom Editor

Tags: php, ubuntu, atom-editor

I installed atom editor and then atom-ctags package. Symbol view package is installed by default.

I am hiting ctrl + r and it says no symbol. However there are methods in my class file thats is openend currently.

I have gone through the issues created at the github repo but did not find any suitable answers

When i do CTRL + R, it says no symbol found
When i do CTRL + SHIFT + R then it pops up the red window with below errors

Here are the errors.

````
[Enter steps to reproduce below:]

1. ...
2. ...

**Atom Version**: 1.0.7
**System**: Ubuntu 14.04.2
**Thrown From**: [symbols-view](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view) package, v0.100.0


### Stack Trace

Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register.

```
At ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:118

Error: Module did not self-register.
  at Error (native)
  at Object.module.(anonymous function) (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:118:20)
  at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:129:18)
  at Module.load (module.js:347:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
  at require (module.js:376:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/node_modules/ctags/lib/ctags.js:4:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/node_modules/ctags/lib/ctags.js:60:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:452:26)
  at Object.loadFile [as .js] (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/babel.js:163:21)
  at Module.load (module.js:347:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
  at require (module.js:376:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/lib/tag-reader.js:6:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/lib/tag-reader.js:66:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:452:26)
  at Object.loadFile [as .js] (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/babel.js:163:21)
  at Module.load (module.js:347:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
  at require (module.js:376:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/lib/project-view.js:14:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/lib/project-view.js:129:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:452:26)
  at Object.loadFile [as .js] (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/babel.js:163:21)
  at Module.load (module.js:347:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
  at require (module.js:376:17)
  at Object.module.exports.createProjectView (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/lib/main.js:73:23)
  at atom-workspace.workspaceSubscription.atom.commands.add.symbols-view:toggle-project-symbols (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/symbols-view/lib/main.js:14:26)
  at CommandRegistry.module.exports.CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/command-registry.js:241:29)
  at /opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/command-registry.js:3:61
  at KeymapManager.module.exports.KeymapManager.dispatchCommandEvent (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/atom-keymap/lib/keymap-manager.js:524:16)
  at KeymapManager.module.exports.KeymapManager.handleKeyboardEvent (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/atom-keymap/lib/keymap-manager.js:347:22)
  at HTMLDocument.module.exports.WindowEventHandler.onKeydown (/opt/atom/resources/app.asar/src/window-event-handler.js:177:20)

```

### Commands

```
     -3:26.4.0 settings-view:open (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
  2x -3:15.9.0 core:backspace (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
  4x -2:00.2.0 atom-ctags:toggle-file-symbols (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
     -1:15.4.0 settings-view:open (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
     -0:55.3.0 command-palette:toggle (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
 23x -0:49.4.0 core:move-down (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
  2x -0:36.2.0 core:move-up (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
     -0:34.4.0 core:confirm (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
     -0:34.4.0 application:run-all-specs (atom-text-editor.editor)
     -0:24.7.0 command-palette:toggle (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
  8x -0:24 core:move-down (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
  4x -0:20.4.0 core:move-up (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
     -0:19.4.0 core:confirm (atom-text-editor.editor.mini.is-focused)
     -0:19.4.0 application:hide-other-applications (atom-text-editor.editor)
  2x -0:14.4.0 symbols-view:toggle-file-symbols (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
     -0:00.8.0 symbols-view:toggle-project-symbols (atom-text-editor.editor.is-focused)
```

### Config

```json
{
  "core": {
    "themes": [
      "one-dark-ui",
      "solarized-dark-syntax"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Installed Packages

```coffee
# User
atom-ctags, v4.2.0
docblockr, v0.7.3
file-icons, v1.6.7

# Dev
No dev packages
```
````